# updating records from multiple tables in pl/sql by triggers

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm looking for help with trigger stuff.

I have tables as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE Autorzy(Id_autora numeric(5), Imie varchar(15), Nazwisko varchar(20), constraint auth_pk PRIMARY KEY (Id_autora));
CREATE TABLE Ksiazki(ISBN numeric(10) PRIMARY KEY, Wydawca varchar(30), Tytul varchar(70), Rok numeric(4));
CREATE TABLE Autorstwa (ISBN numeric(10) references Ksiazki, Id_autora numeric(5) references Autorzy);
CREATE TABLE Tematy (Nrtematu numeric(4) PRIMARY KEY, Nazwa varchar(20), Wyjasnienie varchar (100));
CREATE TABLE Na_temat( ISBN numeric(10) references Ksiazki, Nrtematu numeric(10) references Tematy);

create sequence id_autora_seq
 start with     1
 increment by   1
;

create sequence isbn_seq
  start with    1
  increment by  1
;
```

I have to implement insert for tables Autorzy, Ksiazki and Autorstwa.

I have prepered insert as follows

```
insert into Autorzy 
values( Id_autora_seq.nextval, 'Jan', 'Mak');
insert into Ksiazki
values (isbn_seq.nextval, 'ABC', 'Poradnik', 2010);
```

I dont know how to make update for Autorstwa table.

I tried with triggers as belowe

```
create or replace 
trigger Autorstwa_auth  
   after insert or update on keiishi.Autorzy
   for each row 
begin  
   insert into Autorstwa (Id_autora)
   values (:new.id_autora);
end;

create or replace 
trigger Autorstwa_ks 
  after insert or update on keiishi.Ksiazki
  for each row 
begin  
   insert into Autorstwa (ISBN)
   values (:new.ISBN);
end;
```

It creates two row in Autorstwa table and its unacceptable for me.

Can anyone explain me how to make trigger for multiple tables update?

Or some other method how i can make it?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Keiishi

Answer (score 1):

You might try rewriting your triggers using a MERGE statement.  I'll do one, you can do the other.  :-)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTORSTWA_AUTH
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON KEIISHI.AUTORZY
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO AUTORSTWA a
     USING(SELECT :NEW.ID_AUTORA FROM DUAL) d
       ON (a.ID_AUTORA = d.ID_AUTORA)
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (ID_AUTORA)
         VALUES (:NEW.ID_AUTORA);
END AUTORSTWA_AUTH;
```

Written this way, the MERGE statement will only cause a row to be inserted into AUTORSTWA_AUTH if no matching row already exists.  If you do the same with the other trigger you should only get a single row inserted for a given key value.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I don't understand how this works: it seems there are constraints on fk in Autorstwa in the schema, how can one do an insert in that table without knowing which keys must be used?

Comment: Hi Bob thanks for answer :)
I have tried this and it work after some changes,
USING(SELECT :NEW.ID_AUTORA FROM DUAL)
       ON (a.ID_AUTORA = new:ID_AUTORA)
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (ID_AUTORA)
         VALUES (:NEW.ID_AUTORA);
But unfortunately i still get two row not one.

Comment: Didierc could you tell, what do you mean by 'without knowing keys'? I'm still learning those stuff and mayby i miss something. I see that as 'if i have reference then its to column with the exact name as the one im refering from'. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @Keiishi - I imagine you're getting one row which has the proper value for ID_AUTORA and NULL for ISBN, and another row which has the proper value for ISBN and NULL for ID_AUTORA.  Since neither table, by itself, has both key values it appears you may have to re-think how you're going to put values into AUTORSTWA_AUTH.

Comment: Bob is there something like join in triggers? The best for me would be to import both values at the same time ... but i lack knowledge how to. So i tried with triggers ...

Comment: In the trigger you've only got the data for the table which is being modified, and although you can execute queries against any table except the table which is being changed, I don't think you can get all the data you need to create a row in AUTORSTWA.  I think a better approach might be to write a procedure which takes both the ISBN and the ID_AUTORA as arguments and creates the needed rows in AUTORZY, KSIAZKI, and AUTORSTWA.  Powodzenia.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting the relation incorrectly. In order to update the third table using trigger, with the values of 1st and 2nd table there should be a relation between the two or there should be a table joining 1st and 2nd table.

Answer (score 0):

I changed table Autorstwa to

```
CREATE TABLE Autorstwa (ISBN numeric(10) references Ksiazki(ISBN), Id_autora numeric(5) references Autorzy(Id_Autora), constraint pk_auto PRIMARY KEY (ISBN, Id_autora));
```

As for insert new values into this table, in the end i used normal insert

```
insert into Autorstwa
select max(ISBN), max(Id_Autora) from Ksiazki , Autorzy
```

So i can take lastest value from Ksiazki and Autorzy.

For my needs its ok

At an moment, i don't have time to make procedure for this, but i will make one and post it here, when i will get some free time

Once again thanks you all for advices :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW new_book AS
   SELECT k.ISBN, k.Wydawca, k.Tytul, k.Rok,
            a.Id_Autora, a.Imie, a.Nazwisko
   FROM Autorzy a, Ksiazki k, Autorstwa au
   WHERE a.id_autora = (SELECT au.Id_Autora FROM Autorstwa au WHERE au.ISBN = (SELECT k.ISBN FROM Ksiazki k));

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_book_insert
   INSTEAD OF INSERT ON new_book
   DECLARE
     duplicate_info EXCEPTION;
     PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (duplicate_info, -00001);
   BEGIN

     INSERT INTO Autorzy (Id_Autora, Imie, Nazwisko)
     VALUES (
     :new.Id_Autora,
     :new.Imie,
     :new.Nazwisko);

    INSERT INTO Ksiazki (ISBN, Wydawca, Tytul, Rok)
   VALUES (
     :new.ISBN,
     :new.Wydawca,
     :new.Tytul,
     :new.Rok);

    INSERT INTO Autorstwa (ISBN, Id_Autora)
   VALUES (
     :new.ISBN,
     :new.Id_Autora);
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN duplicate_info THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
         num=> -20107,
         msg=> 'Duplicate Id_Autora or ISBN');
   END new_book_insert;
```